# ASP.Net: How do I find where a class is instantiated?

Tags: asp.net, .net, token, access-token, middleware

I'm debugging ASP.Net API code, and have found that in the following line, `identity` is being set to null, which causes an error to be thrown:

```
var identity = await _options.IdentityResolver(loginDetails, serverDetails);
```

The code that throws the error is

```
    if (identity == null)
    {
        var error = _options.GetFailureError();
        var errorMessage = _options.GetFailureMessage();
        context.Response.StatusCode = 400;

        switch (error)
        {
            case TokenError.HostRetrieval:
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Could not retrieve the login servers for this device");
                break;
            case TokenError.HostValidation:
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Could not validate the login servers for this device");
                break;
            case TokenError.UserLogin:
                var message = String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage) ? "Error occured while trying to authenticate user" : errorMessage;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(message);
                break;
            default:
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Error occured while trying to log in");
                break;
        }

        return;
    }
```

In the switch case, the error is `TokenError.HostValidation`. `loginDetails` and `serverDetails` are as they should be, so I assume `_options.identityResolver` is the problem, so I'm looking for where `_options.identityResolver` is set. This all happens in a class called `TokenProviderMiddleware` that starts like this:

```
public class TokenProviderMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly TokenProviderOptions _options;
        private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _serializerSettings;
        ...
```

The problem is, the only place in the code I can find that references `TokenProviderMiddleware` is this line:

```
app.UseMiddleware<TokenProviderMiddleware>(Options.Create(tokenProviderOptions));
```

and when I set a breakpoint on that line, it doesn't get hit. So I can't figure out where `_options.identityResolver` is set.

Does anyone know how I should approach this? This code uses `CustomTokenProvider` rather than `SimpleTokenProvider`.

Comment: "an error is being thrown" What is the exception? Can you share full details please

Comment: Are you using [SimpleTokenProvider](https://github.com/nbarbettini/SimpleTokenProvider/blob/master/src/SimpleTokenProvider/TokenProviderMiddleware.cs)? If yes, it seems you provided the wrong credentials.

Comment: @OguzOzgul I've edited the post to include the error code.

Comment: @kapsiR I'm using CustomTokenProvider.